# Delete SharePoint items after 90 days. Workflow or OOTB solution?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I need to delete all the items from a library after 90 days. I can easily achieve this by adding a workflow. However are there other Out of the Box option that I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you have Library and Folder Based Retention feature activated on your site collection and follow these steps:

1. Create new content type deriving from Document content type or Item
   content type, it's up to you.
2. Add calculated field of type DateTime with formula '=[Created]' give
   it a name e.g CreatedDate
3. Go to Site Settings -> Web Designer Galleries  -> Site Content Types
   -> *your content type* and click it
4. Once you're on settings page click "Information management policy
   settings"
5. Enable retention and add retention stage using created field and 90
   days as an event trigger for "Move to recycle bin" event.